# Выводит ошибку "500 Internal Server Error" при втором запуске функции

Tags: php

Есть функция:

```
function fetch_server_info($ip, $port){
    $socket = fsockopen($ip, $port, $errno, $errstr, 0.5);
    if ($socket == false){
           return false;
    }
    fwrite($socket, "QUERY_JSON\n");
    $responce = stream_get_contents($socket);
    return json_decode($responce, true);
}
```

Запускаю этим:

```
$info = fetch_server_info(localhost, 3045);
```

Работает но при 2 запуске функции выводит страницу "500 Internal Server Error".
Почему так? Ах, да, версия PHP 5.5.9

Comment: Что в логах пишется в этот момент?

Comment: PHP 5.5 - антикварная версия, вы бы подумали об апгрейде.

Comment: `fclose($socket);`